# Variable magnitudes and principal component analysis

Tags: pca, effect-size

I am completing some PCA on various sets of data, some with 30 time-series variables, some with about 100 (meaning matrices with between 30 and 100 columns).

I know that the covariance matrix is calculated and then the eigenvectors and eigenvalues etc., so we are talking about the relationships between variables.

My understanding: we are aiming to reduce the number of dimensions needed to explain the whole data set as accurately as possible, or expressed in other words, we want to know what the driving factors of a model are. I have read explanations trying to visualise PCA as a body of data. E.g if we have 3 variables, we could say the data represents a 3-d shape. we could have a sphere (all dimensions/variables possess equal weight/importance), a sheet of paper (one dimension is pretty much redundant) or even a piece of string (two dimensions are not very explanatory).

**I want to know, do the actual magnitudes of the original data play a role at all in the end result in PCA?** Is there a way anyone can explain this with similar examples to those I have given?

I am asking because my data (at some point along the time series) underwent a few changes, which meant that only a few of the variables where changed in magnitude - the were scaled down. So the value on one day was 100, it was cut in half to 50, and then all historical data points were retrospectively reduced accordingly.

I want to know if these specific changes affect the output of PCA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's easy enough to experiment and to find out that PCA based on a covariance matrix is necessarily affected by a change of magnitudes. Whether this is a problem depends on why magnitudes were changed and what your aim is. PCA with a covariance matrix only makes sense if the values are comparable (same units of measurement **and** you are interested in actual magnitudes); otherwise use a correlation matrix.

Comment: Magnitudes were changed for exactly the reason of keeping them in a comfortable range. But changes are made to single variables independently of other variable. So if one increased at some point in time, the change on the variable over that same time period, would remain in relative terms the same, but not in absolute terms of course.
Is it generally accepted/equivalent to use a correlation matrix in place of a covariance matrix? In my limited experience, I haven't seen it done.

Comment: If your choice of units is for convenience, analysis based on covariance matrix is indefensible. Far from using a correlation matrix being exceptional, in many fields, and in many programs, it's standard or default procedure.